Steam через Wine на Arch Linux
Пытаюсь запустить Стим через Wine но сразу после входа в аккаунт он вылетает, нативный Стим под Линукс мне не подходит, если что система Arch linux

Чем нативный стим не угодил? У меня на арче он прекрасно работает.

Читайте что с января месяца, steam не поддерживает устаревшие windows, так что быть может проблема в этом

Пробовал использовать PortProton? Запускал и Steam, и EGS, и другие лаунчеры через него без проблем на разных дистрибутивах.

Мне что-то подсказывает, что вы думаете, что нативный стим не умеет запускать виндовые игры (умеет через proton), или умеет но не все (умеет все, надо в настройках поставить галочку, чтобы разрешать запускать даже непроверенные игры).

мне стим нужен по другой причине, пиратки со стим фиксом без стима не работают

попробуй отключить ускорение вэб компонентов
Steam top left>Settings>interface
Disable GPU accelerated rendering in web view

Как? меня даже в аккаунт не пускает, всё что я вижу это получение данных пользователя и все, вылет
